# Error: The underlying provider failed on Open. How to resolve it?

Tags: c#, sql, using

I have function that with code similar to this:

```
using(var db = new MyDbContext())
{
    //a whole bunch of code, db is working.

    //then I try opening another DbContext like so
    using(var dba = new AnotherDbContext())
    {
        //about 2 lines of code just to get something from a database
    }
}
```

And then I get 2 error messages when I get to the second DbContext:

"The underlying provider failed on Open." & "MSDTC on server 'myserver' is unavailable."

Does anybody know the reason why this is happening? Can I open 2 DbContexts at once?

Comment: Ehm, mixing two contexts/databases/whatever in a single method is usually a very bad idea in programming in general. Why exactly do you need to do it like this? Sounds like a bad architectural design so far...

Comment: I use one database to store CanadaPost information that I can use in all of my projects. @walther

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first scenario, you are nesting **AnotherDbContext**. A connection to the database is opened for each on of them. When you call your service method within the using block, a new connection is opened within the **MyDbContextwhile** there is another one already open. 
This causes your transaction to be promoted to a distributed transaction, and partially committed data (the result of the **dba.SaveChanges** call in the service) not being available from your outer connection.Also note that distributed transactions are far slower and thus, this has the side effect of degrading performance.

```
private void btnTwoConnectionsNested_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connectionString = @"Data Source=" + tbServer.Text
        + @";Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True; timeout=0";

    using (TransactionScope transactionScope = new TransactionScope())
    {
        SqlConnection connectionOne = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlConnection connectionTwo = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

        try
        {
            //2 connections, nested
            connectionOne.Open();
            connectionTwo.Open(); // escalates to DTC on 05 and 08
            connectionTwo.Close();
            connectionOne.Close();

            MessageBox.Show("Success");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ERROR: " + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            connectionOne.Dispose();
            connectionTwo.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Within one Transaction Scope, it will open two connections, nested. 
 The result:

Against SQL Server 2005 Instance:
          MSDTC on server ‘SERVERNAME’ is unavailable.

Against SQL Server 2008 Instance:
          MSDTC on server ‘SERVERNAME’ is unavailable.

SQL Server does, and should, escalate to DTC for a nested connection in both versions.

Nested connections will escalate to DTC in SQL Server 2005 and 2008.  Opening one connection at a time will escalate to DTC in 2005, but WILL NOT in 2008.